# Part of rigged mesh doesn't move with the rig

Tags: mesh, rigging

I created this mesh, then made a rig for it and did everything right with the IK rigging.

As I go to test it I turned the head and half of the face doesn't move with it. I kept trying a multitude of things to get it to move but it just stays there. Can anyone Help me?

Things I have tried Re-rigging it and reapplying the mirror modifier.

Comment: Hard to say what could be wrong without seeing the file. We could compile a list of the most likely reasons but it's oft best to have a definitive answer. Can you upload the file and post the link here.

Comment: And listing the multitude of things you've tried can narrow down the list of possible solutions.

Comment: Have you already checked the weight paint?

Answer (score 1):

If some vertices are not influenced by the movement of the deformation bone probably the don't have enough weight assigned. In *Object Mode* select the bone first than the mesh, change to *Weight Paint* and add more weight to the vertices (blue is completly unbiased).

[image]